# SAP GUI Manage system messages popup

Tags: ui-automation, sap-gui

Since now 2 days, I'm trying to find a way to manage this popup into SAP GUI scripting:
[image: System messages]

This is how it's behaving. Once the script logged in into SAP this popup is display. If we accept it, it will not be displayed until the next days.

As you can see the icon to access to recording and playback is disabled... It means I cannot (or I don't know how) get the button id and click to accept it...

Any one of you already managed it in the past ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The popup of System Messages corresponds to the screen **`0600`** of program **`SAPMSEM1`**.

[image: System Messages]

You may do this kind of code to bypass it:

```
If Session.Info.Program = "SAPMSEM1" And Session.Info.ScreenNumber = "0600" Then
  Session.ActiveWindow.SendVKey 0
End If
```

References:

- [GuiSessionInfo Object](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=GuiSessionInfo%20Object&product=sap_gui_for_windows)
- [GuiSession Object](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=GuiSession%20Object&product=sap_gui_for_windows)